# ¿Las comunidades de stack exchange pueden postularse como un Collective?

Tags: discusión

Seguro ya saben del revuelo que está causando la característica recientemente añadida de los colectivos.

¿Qué opinan de que aquellos que participamos activamente en esta comunidad y seamos además angloparlantes formemos un colectivo dentro de SOen?

---

Links agregados por moderador>

[pagina principal](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives)
[post en meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408585/beta-release-of-collectives-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: Yo no conozco esa nueva característica, podrías añadir un enlace?

Comment: Me parece que no entendiste como venia la cosa.. no vas a poder hacer algo asi, porque no sos un colectivo en la forma en la que ellos lo armaron... que tipo de preguntas, que etiquetas serian las de tu colectivo?

Answer (score 1):

Respuesta corta: El anuncio oficial no menciona esta posibilidad -> Véase [Beta release of Collectives™ on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/408585/1595451).

---

Según entiendo, "Collectives" es una característica que está en Beta. Los "Collectives" son creados por empleados designados por Stack Overflow para agrupar etiquetas<sup>1,2,3</sup> que entre otras cosas son respaldadas por una organización y usuarios expertos seleccionados.

Por lo pronto si nos interesan alguno de los "Collectives" existentes podemos unirnos, independientemente de eso además ver cómo evoluciona el Beta y esperar más anuncios por parte de Stack Overflow.

Con respecto a tener un "International Collective", es decir en un idioma diferente al inglés, dudo mucho que vaya a ocurrir durante el Beta.

Actualización:

En sitios de SE en inglés como Web Applications, el día de hoy se muestra un banner con la liga a un Podcast sobre esta iniciativa. El texto del banner es

> We just launched a new product: Collectives on Stack Overflow. How do they work? [Listen to learn more](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/06/25/podcast-351-collectives-on-stack-overflow/?_ga=2.43240103.366390970.1623619081-1790901638.1623619081).

Relacionado:

1: [How are collective tags chosen?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/408701/1595451)
2: https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud?tab=tags
3: https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/go?tab=tags

Comment: No son creados por los empleados (segun lo que entendi), son pagos, y esponsorizados por empresas (u organizaciones sin fines de lucro)... y se supone que no agrupan etiquetas.. tienen una sola etiqueta particular de una tecnologia... ahora si entendi mal please corregime!!!

Comment: jeje, Si tuvieras razón, "nos son creados por empleados" los crearía un "no-empleado".... ¿Tu crees que es lógico que SO deje a un no empleado meterse con un Beta?

Comment: En cuanto a que tienen una única etiqueta, cuando tengas tiempo mira cualquiera de las páginas de los "Collectives"... tienen una página de "tags" similar a la página de "tags" del sitio completo. De hecho en algún comentario se dió retro sobre una etiqueta que no debía incluirse en "Golang Collective"

Comment: me referia a que se crean a pedido de una empresa (o una entidad sin fines de lucro)... pero bue... lo de las etiquetas ahora lo miro, al principio habian puesto solo una...

Comment: Los dos "collectives" son sobre temas de Google. No he prestado tanta atención como para tener claro si fue pedido por Google o propuesto por SO así como tampoco para saber si hay una convocatoria abierta para otras empresas pidan un "collective"

Comment: si. esta claro que es un producto pago, no los creo SO para si mismo, si no que es un convenio con google. google esta pagando por esto... y las empresas que quieran los suyos tienen que pagar.

Comment: los usuarios expertos asi como los administradores son seleccionados por la empresa (no SO, la empresa que esponsoriza).. esa es una de las criticas al proyecto...

Comment: Quitada la parte de quien los selecciona. El que quiera ver ese detalle que vaya a Meta SO :D